# React - how to click outside to close the tooltip

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my current tooltip.

I am using [react-power-tooltip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-power-tooltip)

When I click the button, I can close the tooltip.

But I want to close the tooltip when I click outside the tooltip.

How am I supposed to do it?

[image]

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import MoreHorizIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoreHoriz";
import TooltipList from "./TooltipList";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [showTooltip, setShowTooltip] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        className="post-section__body__list__item__right__menu-btn"
        onClick={() => {
          setShowTooltip((x) => !x);
        }}
        style={{ position: "relative" }}
      >
        <MoreHorizIcon />
        <TooltipList show={showTooltip} />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

TooltipList

```
import React from "react";
import Tooltip from "react-power-tooltip";

const options = [
  {
    id: "edit",
    label: "Edit"
  },
  {
    id: "view",
    label: "View"
  }
];

function Tooptip(props) {
  const { show } = props;
  return (
    <Tooltip
      show={show}
      position="top center"
      arrowAlign="end"
      textBoxWidth="180px"
      fontSize="0.875rem"
      fontWeight="400"
      padding="0.5rem 1rem"
    >
      {options.map((option) => {
        return (
          <div
            className="tooltop__option d-flex align-items-center w-100"
            key={option.id}
          >
            {option.icon}
            <span style={{ fontSize: "1rem" }}>{option.label}</span>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </Tooltip>
  );
}

export default Tooptip;
```

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-morning-m9eq3?file=/src/App.js

**Update 1:**

I update the code based on the answer.
It can now click outside to close, but if I click the button to close the tooltip, it's not working.

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import MoreHorizIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoreHoriz";
import TooltipList from "./TooltipList";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [showTooltip, setShowTooltip] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        className="post-section__body__list__item__right__menu-btn"
        onClick={() => {
          setShowTooltip((x) => !x);
        }}
        style={{ position: "relative" }}
      >
        <MoreHorizIcon />
        <TooltipList
          show={showTooltip}
          onClose={() => {
            setShowTooltip();
          }}
        />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

TooltipList.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Tooltip from "react-power-tooltip";

const options = [
  {
    id: "edit",
    label: "Edit"
  },
  {
    id: "view",
    label: "View"
  }
];

function Tooptip(props) {
  const { show, onClose } = props;

  const containerRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (show) {
      containerRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [show]);

  return (
    <div
      style={{ display: "inline-flex" }}
      ref={containerRef}
      tabIndex={0}
      onBlur={(e) => {
        onClose();
      }}
    >
      <Tooltip
        show={show}
        position="top center"
        arrowAlign="end"
        textBoxWidth="180px"
        fontSize="0.875rem"
        fontWeight="400"
        padding="0.5rem 1rem"
      >
        {options.map((option) => {
          return (
            <div
              className="tooltop__option d-flex align-items-center w-100"
              key={option.id}
            >
              {option.icon}
              <span style={{ fontSize: "1rem" }}>{option.label}</span>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </Tooltip>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Tooptip;
```

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-morning-m9eq3?file=/src/App.js:572-579

Comment: Are you going to keep the menu open when the component loads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I can see, you are using material-ui for icons, so there is an option known as [ClickAwayListner](https://material-ui.com/components/click-away-listener/) within material-ui

App.js

```js
import "./styles.css";
import MoreHorizIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoreHoriz";
import ClickAwayListener from '@material-ui/core/ClickAwayListener';
import TooltipList from "./TooltipList";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [showTooltip, setShowTooltip] = useState(true);
  const handleClickAway = () => {
    setShowTooltip(false);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClickAway}>
        <button
          className="post-section__body__list__item__right__menu-btn"
          onClick={e => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            setShowTooltip((x) => !x);
          }}
          style={{ position: "relative" }}
        >
          <MoreHorizIcon />
          <TooltipList show={showTooltip} />
        </button>
      </ClickAwayListener>
    </div>
    
  );
}
```

Wrap your container with `ClickAwayListener`

Comment: Is it ok to wrap `ClickAwayListener ` for `TooltipList` component?

Comment: Better to wrap your `button` with `ClickAwayListener`

Comment: When I click the button, `handleClickAway` and `() => {
            setShowTooltip((x) => !x);
          }`  both trigger, which make me cannot open the tooltip

Comment: Please see my `Update 1`

Comment: @CCCC I have updated my answer please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a wrapper element to detect if the click is outside a component
then the showTooltip to false at your code:
[codeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-robinson-p10kk?file=/src/App.js:0-1026)

```
   import "./styles.css";
   import MoreHorizIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoreHoriz";
   import TooltipList from "./TooltipList";
   import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
   
   export default function App() {
     const [showTooltip, setShowTooltip] = useState(true);
     const outsideClick = (ref) => {
       useEffect(() => {
         const handleOutsideClick = (event) => {
           if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
             setShowTooltip(false);
           }
         };
         // add the event listener
         document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleOutsideClick);
       }, [ref]);
     };
     const wrapperRef = useRef(null);
     outsideClick(wrapperRef);
     return (
       <div className="App" ref={wrapperRef}>
         <button
           className="post-section__body__list__item__right__menu-btn"
           onClick={() => {
             setShowTooltip((x) => !x);
           }}
           style={{ position: "relative" }}
         >
           <MoreHorizIcon />
           <TooltipList show={showTooltip} />
         </button>
       </div>
     );
   }
```

Comment: Please see my `Update 1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a crazy little idea. I wrapped your component in an `inline-flex` div and gave it focus on load. Then added an onBlur event which will hide the menu if you click anywhere else. This can be used if you don't want to give focus on any other element on the page.

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-kapitsa-yh7si?file=/src/App.js:0-940

```
import "./styles.css";
import MoreHorizIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoreHoriz";
import TooltipList from "./TooltipList";
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [showTooltip, setShowTooltip] = useState(true);
  const containerRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    containerRef.current.focus();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
         style={{ display: "inline-flex" }}
        ref={containerRef}
        tabIndex={0}
        onBlur={(e) => {
          debugger;
          setShowTooltip(false);
        }}
      >
        <button
          className="post-section__body__list__item__right__menu-btn"
          onClick={() => {
            setShowTooltip((x) => !x);
          }}
          style={{ position: "relative" }}
        >
          <MoreHorizIcon />

          <TooltipList show={showTooltip} />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Update 1:**

The problem was your button click was called every time you select an item that toggles your state. I have updated the code to prevent that using a `useRef` that holds a value.

ToolTip:

```
import React from "react";
import Tooltip from "react-power-tooltip";

const options = [
  {
    id: "edit",
    label: "Edit"
  },
  {
    id: "view",
    label: "View"
  }
];

function Tooptip(props) {
  const { show, onChange } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <Tooltip
        show={show}
        position="top center"
        arrowAlign="end"
        textBoxWidth="180px"
        fontSize="0.875rem"
        fontWeight="400"
        padding="0.5rem 1rem"
      >
        {options.map((option) => {
          return (
            <div
              onClick={onChange}
              className="tooltop__option d-flex align-items-center w-100"
              key={option.id}
            >
              {option.icon}
              <span style={{ fontSize: "1rem" }}>{option.label}</span>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </Tooltip>
    </>
  );
}

export default Tooptip;
```

App

```
import "./styles.css";
import MoreHorizIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoreHoriz";
import TooltipList from "./TooltipList";
import { useRef, useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [showTooltip, setShowTooltip] = useState(true);
  const [onChangeTriggered, setonChangeTriggered] = useState(false);
  const containerRef = useRef();
  const itemClicked = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    containerRef.current.focus();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        style={{ display: "inline-flex" }}
        ref={containerRef}
        tabIndex={0}
        onBlur={(e) => {
          debugger;
          if (!onChangeTriggered) setShowTooltip(false);
        }}
        // onFocus={() => {
        //   setShowTooltip(true);
        // }}
      >
        <button
          className="post-section__body__list__item__right__menu-btn"
          onClick={() => {
            if (!itemClicked.current) setShowTooltip((x) => !x);
            itemClicked.current = false;
          }}
          style={{ position: "relative" }}
        >
          <MoreHorizIcon />

          <TooltipList
            show={showTooltip}
            onChange={useCallback(() => {
              itemClicked.current = true;
            }, [])}
          />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-kapitsa-yh7si

Enjoy !!

Comment: Not working, also your code here is different from codesandbox

Comment: I am seeing the results fine. Is this working for you? https://yh7si.csb.app/. I had tried the MUI solution before maybe you were seeing old code. The current one works fine for me. Let me know.

Comment: Open the result in a new window.

Comment: When I click the option, the tooltip close also, is it possible to solve it?

Comment: I tried a few things but my onBlur event is not the one closing the menu. I assume the library does that by default. I have updated the code sandbox with my efforts to keep it open. No option on the library to keep it open.

Comment: Please see my `Update 1`

Comment: Check the update. It took a lot of time to figure that out. I will appreciate thumps up at least !!